# Not able to generate DKIM record for .net domain in google app

Tags: dns, google-apps, spf, dkim

I'm using `google apps` for mail service. I have generated and submitted DKIM records for .co and .in domains successfully. But I'm not able to generate DKIM record for .net domain (say yourdomain.net). It shows an error `we are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later. (Error #1000)`. I have tried this for 2 .net domains. Both provide the same error. I have tried using in different browser and different machine, and the results are the same.

I am not sure if the issue is with the .net domain or if this is just a coincidence.

Comment: Same problem here, with a .net domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a "Google Apps for Work" account and wanted to setup DKIM for Google Apps email and another provider and I couldn't do it. I contacted Google Apps support and they said it was a bug with no immediate plans to fix it.

I got the same useless error code you did. I'm disappointed in Google about this. They just leave the broken submit form up, leaving it to the user to contact support to find out it's broken with no plans to fix it.

I'm going to cancel my paying google apps account.

Comment: After 2 days, I have generated record without any error. Before that I have raised case in Google support. They responded after a week.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue today (setup of DKIM on a new GSuite domain) and chatted with Google Support about it.

They pointed me to the following quote on [the DKIM setup process](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174126).

> **Important:** After you create your G Suite account and turn on Gmail, you must wait 24–72 hours before you can generate a DKIM domain key.

So you'll need to wait 24 - 72 hours after setup of the GSuite account before you can set up DKIM.

---

I also asked the support person whether I could get access to submit this as a product request (that the DKIM setup is prevented before this time) and he gave me access to [the G Suite Feature Ideas (customers only) Cloud Connect Community](https://www.cloudconnectcommunity.com/ccc/ls/community/g-suite-chrome-feature-ideas/posts). I've posted this as a feature suggestion there - upvote if you think this is needed! (needs login):

https://www.cloudconnectcommunity.com/ccc/ls/community/g-suite-chrome-feature-ideas/post/5075513382141952

Preview Screenshot:

[image: GSuite Feature Ideas: Better DKIM Workflow with New GSuite Account]

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error message when I tried to set up `DKIM` immediately after signing up for GSuite. It worked when I re-tried about two days later.